# How to keep background image on css gradient

Tags: css

I have created a css gradient.Am trying to place a image above that.Below is my code.

```
style.css
.body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:70%;
   border-style:dotted solid;
   border-color:#38FFBE;
}
.container {
   height:90%;
   position:relative;
}
.header {
   padding:10px;
   height:40%;
   border-style:dotted solid;
   border-color:#38FFBE;
   background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(95,255,41) 41%, rgb(156,255,255) 71%, rgb(232,171,235) 86%);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(95,255,41) 41%, rgb(156,255,255) 71%, rgb(232,171,235) 86%);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(95,255,41) 41%, rgb(156,255,255) 71%, rgb(232,171,235) 86%);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(95,255,41) 41%, rgb(156,255,255) 71%, rgb(232,171,235) 86%);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(95,255,41) 41%, rgb(156,255,255) 71%, rgb(232,171,235) 86%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(95,255,41)),
    color-stop(0.71, rgb(156,255,255)),
    color-stop(0.86, rgb(232,171,235))
);

background: url(apples.jpg) no-repeat left bottom, -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #2F2727, #1a82f7) ;
background: url(apples.jpg) no-repeat left bottom, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
}
.body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background-color:#CAFF70;
}
.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:80px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#CAFF70;
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>MindBest</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
<%@include file="../include/style.css"%>
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="body">Body</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the above code.but the gradient is totally changed.can anyone please help me to align the image to left side of gradient.As am new to css.Can anyone help?

Comment: Its urgent..thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/VPjP9/

I added an image to the first serie of gradients (I deleted those that were along apple.jpg, couldn't understand what they were doing there) with the property `background-image` and then wrote `background-position` and `background-repeat` for these multiple images (image and gradient).

As there are numerous vendor prefixes to manage, it's easier to just write what is needed for the `background-image` part and then write once for all browsers `background-position` and `background-repeat` that doesn't need any vendor prefix.

Comment: Yeah Felipe am trying somewaht like this.I want to place multiple images and would like to align at diff positions How to i align that?

Comment: You can change the value of `background-position`, `background-position: 50px center, left top;` for example. Before the comma is the above one (your image)

Comment: Need one more help..In this case the image is placed over gradient.I need something where gradients masks the image

Comment: With some transparency in the gradient? Just exchange left and right side of the comma in each value of various properties `background-*`. From left to right, it goes from *above* to *below* layers of images. Don't forget to add a `background-color` as a fallback to browsers that won't understand either gradients and/or multiple backgrounds (in the latter case, you should also add a single `background-image: url(apple.jpg)`  before this serie of multiple backgrounds instructions).